# When will SoftLayer_Product_Package::getLocations() be disabled?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

SoftLayer support asked me to ask this question here at stack overflow,
so I am asking here and hopefully someone internal can answer...

According to January 11, 2016 note from here:
  https://softlayer.github.io/release_notes/

SoftLayer_Product_Package::getLocations() is deprecated.
When will it be disabled?  January 18th?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently a date when **SoftLayer_Product_Package::getLocations** method will be disabled. So as the release notes, we recommend to use [SoftLayer_Product_Package::getRegions](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getRegions), since it contains the correct data.